# How access variables inside method? (python)

Tags: python, class

Is it possible to access `self.bin` outside the class?

```
class kon():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def add(self):
        con=7
        self.bin=100

h=kon()

bin=h.bin
```

In one topic advised to use `self.` before variables but it did not work.
Maybe such variables must be in `__init__` method.

Comment: You have not called `h.add()` so `bin` is not set. Either do it in `__init__` or call `h.add`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). It will be very useful for you.

> The instantiation operation (“calling” a class object) creates an empty object. Many classes like to create objects with instances customized to a specific initial state. Therefore a class may define a special method named **init**(), like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.bin = 0
```

> When a class defines an **init**() method, class instantiation automatically invokes **init**() for the newly-created class instance.

After this you can use this property in you object, to read or assign value.

Also, there is a difference between initialize properties in the class. From the docs:

```
class Dog:
    kind = 'canine'         # class variable shared by all instances
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name    # instance variable unique to each instance
```